# Acces to the parent of the iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

There is a website (**S**), that contains an iframe (**A**), that displays my site. What I need, is to add an iframe (**B**) from my site to the parent page (**S**) with javascript. I coded something, but this adds the new iframe (**B**) to the iframe's (**A**) content, not to the parent's (**S**)

The website (**S**) is not the same domain.

Code on my site:

```
<script>

    function GetFrame() 
    { 
        ifrm = window.document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://stackoverflow.com/"); 
        ifrm.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 25%; border: none;"); 

        window.document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].appendChild(ifrm);
    } 

</script>


<img src="image.jpg" onload="GetFrame()"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you want to add iframe **B** to **S**, you'll need **S** to run the script for you, either by fetching it with `<script src="SCRIPT_URL"></script>` or by defining it inline with `<script>YOUR_SCRIPT</script>`.